# How to modify HTTP Responses on android?

Tags: networking, android, http, sniffing, http-proxy

I have an Android Device which is capable of running both Linux And Android Side by side, I need to keep checking the packets being sent by the device to a particular domain, And when the domain meets the filter, I need to modify the http response for the request, how do i do it ? All of this I need to do on the same device.